# transition not work in svg

Tags: jquery, svg, transition

I'm trying to add attribute on svg which the target already set transition on css. When I try use with css hover it work fine.

somehow I'd like to add as attribute on svg with jquery. It work as well, problem is why the target is losing transition effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#Layer_1').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('.groupAni').attr('transform','rotate(180)');
  },function(){
   $(this).find('.groupAni').removeAttr('transform');
 });
});
```

```css
  .container{
   width: 1170px;
   margin: auto;
  }
  .box{
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   background-color: yellow;
  }
  .groupAni{
   transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  }
    /*  #Layer_1:hover .groupAni{
   cursor: pointer;
   transform: rotate(360deg);
  }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-300 -200 800 800" enable-background="new 0 0 139.9 217.3" xml:space="preserve">
   <g class="groupAni">
    <rect x="0.6" y="86.6" fill="#945BA5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="100" height="100"/>
    <circle fill="#ED1F24" cx="4.3" cy="90.3" r="2.5"/>
   </g>
   <circle fill="#81C341" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="93.5" cy="170.9" r="46.5"/>
   <polygon fill="#FEED50" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="38.3,96 20.6,42.3 58.2,0 113.7,11.5 131.4,65.2  93.7,107.5 "/>
  </svg>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your are modifying your element's attributes, while CSS transitions look for changes in CSS attributes. You'll want to set this transform thanks to their css attributes instead (`$(this).find('.groupAni').css('transform','rotate(180deg)');`)

Comment: Is that posible keep use attribute to run the animation?

Comment: Not in svg1.1, dunno in SVG2. But why would you do it ? CSS attributes have precedence over XML attributes. It's just fine to use css for this, even if controlled from js.